# automated macOS file sync similar to Microsoft offline files

Tags: osx, file-synchronization, synchronization, macos

I use multiple Apple computers and need to sync files between them. To make my life a bit easier, I am considering to run a server that is available 24/7. However, I would like something automated, i.e. a software that automatically syncs the files in the background (i.e. without me having to manually launch the sync).

On Windows I like the way the builtin offline files tool works. Is there something similar for macOS?

In general I prefer low-tech and open-source solutions. For instance, something that uses rsync would be great. I am not interested in any cloud solutions like iCloud because I have too much data and would prefer to keep it on my on devices.